# Rest APIs or Database for Vaccinations and Allergies

Tags: api, medical, database, healthcare-finder-api

I am doing research and looking for an API for Vaccination and Allergies. I found some link like  https://data.cdc.gov/ where I can the information but I am looking for something which has all information in one dataset or API. Please advise